# Form theme that only applies to templates in a particular bundle

Tags: forms, symfony

How I can set form theme for bundle? In documentation is an example

```
twig:
    form:
        resources:
            - 'AcmeTaskBundle:Form:form_div_layout.html.twig'
```

But this form theming to each form in application.
If use

`{% form_theme form 'AcmeTaskBundle:Form:fields.html.twig' %}`

Uncomfortable, because you need write for each form in application.

For example I have 2 main layout and 2 bundle (backend and frontend) and want form theming for each of this bundles. How I can do this? Any ideas?

Comment: If you find the answer please let us know. Thanks

Comment: @Mikhail I didn't found any solutions, sorry :(

Answer (score 1):

I think you can use template inheritance.

Put you form_theme call in one of your base layout and every template that inherits from it will use the good form theme.

UPDATE: This may not be possible because you dan't have any reference to the FormView actaully used.

Comment: Of course I tried this. I can use `{% if form is defined %}` but this not good way